# Sequence of functions $\{ g_n \}$ such that $g_n \in L^1, g_n \to 0 $ a.e $\mu$, $\int g_n \to 0$, but no $g \in L^1$ such that $\sup g_n(x) \leq g $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the following question:

> Suppose we have a finite measure space with the property that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a measurable $A$ such that $0<\mu(A) < \epsilon$. Prove there is a sequence of  measurable functions $\{g_n\}$ such that $g_n \in L^1, g_n \to 0 $ a.e $\mu$, $\int g_n \to 0$, but no $g \in L^1$ such that $\sup g_n(x) \leq g $

I am not really sure what to do. I tried looking at simple functions. Specifically, for each $n$, pick $A_n$ such that $0 < \mu(A_n) < 1/n$ and consider the sequence $g_n = \sqrt{n}\chi_{A_n}$. Then, the sequence $\{ g_n\}$ satisfies the first two properties, but I don't know if there exists $g \in L^1$ such that $\sup g_n(x) \leq g $.

Comment: the idea is good but you need to move $A_n$ around in the sense that for each $n$ you cover $X$ (or a subset of positive measure enough as $X$ may have atoms etc ) with finitely many sets $A_{n.k}, k=1,..m_n$ of measure less than $1/n$ and define $g_{n,k}$ as you did and reindex them to make a sequence in an obvious way (in increasing of order of $n$) then $\sup g_m(x) =\infty$ since each $x$ is in some $A_{n,k}$ so there is a $g_{q_n}(x) \ge \sqrt n$, while obviously the rest of the conditions hold

Comment: What do you mean by "move $A_n$ around"? For all I know, the $A_n$ are nested inside each other.

Comment: Show that the hypothesis implies that there is a non atomic part of positive mass ($Y$ st the hypothesis applied for all measurable subsets of it)